# Como hacer Includes en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, views

**Mi versión de Laravel es 6.3.0**

Estoy empezando a usar laravel y estoy teniendo problemas para hacer includes, tras realiza una búsqueda se que en laravel se usa el `@include`. Lo que yo intento es que según en que apartado del navbar clicke el usuario se incluya dicha vista pero me está dando error en el código de php que tengo insertado.

Mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url('/css/style.css') }}" />
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>
<title>MaxCenter</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="navbar">
  <div id="myTopnav" class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="pags active"><a href="?page=home">Inicio</a></li>
      <li class="pags"><a href="?page=shop">Tienda1</a></li>
      <li class="pags"><a href="?page=shop">Tienda2</a></li>
      <li><a id="logo" href="#top"><img src="{{ url('/img/logo.png') }}" 
       alt="logo"></a></li>
      <li class="pags last"><a href="?page=shop">Tienda3</a></li>
      <li class="pags last"><a href="?page=shop">Tienda4</a></li>
      <li class="pags dropdown">
        <a class="dropbtn" href="?page=home">Centro</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#horario">Horario</a>
          <a href="#mapa">Mapa</a>
          <a href="#contacto">Contáctanos</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="{{ url('/img/bars.png') }}" alt="bras"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Incluimos las vistas aquí -->
  <?php
   $p = $_GET['page']; // el error me da en ésta línea.
   if(isset($p)  && $p != 'home') {
     if(file_exists($p)) {
       @include ($p);
     } else{
       echo "Error 404, something was wrong.";
     }
   }else {
     @include('home');
   }
 ?>

<section class="footer">
  <div class="tgfo">
    <div class="tgfo1">
      <h2>Soporte</h2>
      <p>Correo electrónico</p>
      <p>Asistencia Tel.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tgfo2">
      <h2>Servicios</h2>
      <p>Cines</p>
      <p>Bolera</p>
      <p>Tiendas/Restaurantes</p>
    </div>
    <h1>MAXCENTER</h1>
    <div class="tgfo3">
      <h2>Síguenos</h2>
      <p>Facebook</p>
      <p>Twitter</p>
      <p>Instagram</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tgfo4">
      <h2>Términos Legales</h2>
      <p>Política de Privacidad</p>
      <p>Condiciones de compra</p>
      <p>© Sonae Sierra 2019 Todos los derechos reservados</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Y aquí os muestro las vistas que tengo:

[image: estructura de views]

El error que me da laravel es el siguiente:

> Undefined index: page (View: /home/ubuntu/laravel6/blog/resources/views/index.blade.php)
>   resources/views/index.blade.php:33

**Edición:**

web.php
Éste llama a un controlador el cual le devolverá la vista.

```
Route::get('/', 'ShopController@index');
```

Controlador ShopController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $shops = Shop::all();
    return view('index',['shops'=>$shops]);
}
```

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: No estás recibiendo la variable `page` en tu vista. Muéstranos el código de tu controlador y la ruta que tienes en el archivo web.php

Comment: Edito la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olvidate de utilizar `$_GET` y `$_POST` en Laravel, para manejar esto tienes la clase `Request`. Igualmente la lógica deberías realizarla en el controlador no en la vista.

Una solición podría ser:

**Ruta**

```
Route::get('/', 'ShopController@index');
```

**ShopController.php**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // optenemos lo que que necesitemos
    $shops = Shop::all();
    // verivicamos si existe ?page y la vista 
    if($request->has('page') AND View::exists($request->page)) {
        // retornamos la vista que solicitemos
        return view($request->page, ['shops'=>$shops]);
    }
    // si no existe retornamos home
    return view('home', ['shops'=>$shops]);
}
```

En cuanto a las vistas, deberias tener una base o layout y las demas vistas que extiendan de ella, con `@yield` indicamos donde se insertara el contenido de la subplantilla, ejemplo, acortare todo lo que pueda para que quede clara la idea:

**layout.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora en el resto de subplantillas, `home.blade.php`, `shop.blade.php` ... utilizamos **@extends** para extender del layout principal y **@section** para indicar en que @yeild del padre va. Por ejemplo para shop.blade.php:

**shop.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
    Aquí el cuerpo shop.blade.php
@endsection
```

y lo mismo para cualquier otra.

---

Documentación Laravel blade: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade

Comment: @include no me funcionaría igual??

Comment: Mas o menos si, pero si he entendido lo que quieres hacer el uso de include de la manera que quieres hace que traslades la lógica a la vista. Es recomensable que utilices el include principalmente para partes estaticas, por ejemplo, separar el footer. Ademas supongo que para los diferentes shop que quieres mostrar tendras datos diferentes y esto lo tendras que manejar desde el controlador, asi por que no tener junto que datos traer y que vista mostrar en el controlador...

Comment: Muchas gracias :D